# OBSOLETE - Review+Edit Page

Tags: script, obsolete, chrome-extensions

> ## Obsolete: The links are all dead.  No source code.

This Chrome extension  reorganizes the Review page of Stack Exchange sites, adding lists of questions that may need an intervention.

The review tasks are moved to the sidebar, freeing the main column for two lists of questions:

1. New questions with at least one downvote (excluding closed questions). Both upvote and downvote counts are shown for these questions.
2. Recently active questions with potentially bad titles.

The idea is that these are the questions that the reviewer may want to edit or close.

[image: screenshot]

The quality of titles is judged by a simple regex; false positives happen.

---

<del>[Available from Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/review%20-page/nfaaglhemabjbpddkbahiogfclhkablj)</del>

Plain JavaScript, Stack Exchange API 2.2, [WTFPL](http://www.wtfpl.net/).
<del>[Source files](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r9q3sgyibsrzsjp/reviewPro.zip)</del> (Dead link)